# Exporting variables with multiple values?

Tags: java, file, text, export

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;

public class AvgTime {

static double hrs1;
static double min1;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException {

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("How many times? ");
int numOfTimes = in.nextInt();

double hrTotal = 0;
double minTotal = 0;

for (int i = 1; i <= numOfTimes; i++){

  System.out.println("\nEnter time in military time notation: ");
  System.out.print("Hour  ");
  double hrs1 = in.nextDouble();
  System.out.print("Minute  ");
  double min1 = in.nextDouble();



  hrTotal += hrs1;
  minTotal += min1;
}

//calculate average
double avgHr1 = hrTotal/numOfTimes;
double timeMin1 = Math.round(minTotal/numOfTimes);


DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###");
String hours = df.format(avgHr1);
String minutes = df.format(timeMin1);

String time = hours+":"+minutes+":"+00;
String mt = hours+minutes;


    SimpleDateFormat fmtMil = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Date inDate = fmtMil.parse(time, new ParsePosition(0));
    SimpleDateFormat fmtAMPM = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
    StringBuffer outDate = fmtAMPM.format(inDate, new StringBuffer(), new FieldPosition(0));
System.out.println("\nThe average time is " + outDate+"\n"+mt+" in military time.\n\n");

    String copy = "Copying...";

    Thread.sleep( 550 );
    for( int i = 0; i < copy.length(); i++ ) {
        System.out.print(copy.charAt( i ) );
         try{ Thread.sleep( 105 ); }catch( Exception e ){}
        }


        PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter("Times.txt");
           p.println(hrs1+min1);
            p.close();


        System.out.println("\nDone\n\n\n");
            Thread.sleep( 550 );
  }
}
```

I want it to export to a file the times entered by the user. For example if the user sets the numOfTimes to be 2, I will have 2 different values for hrs1 and min1.

Say they enter: 1629 and 2018.

I want the text file to display the hrs1 (16) and the min1 (29) just like 1629. But instead of the 'hrs1+min1' when I put hrs1+min1 it just exports '0.0'. I just want it to export "1629" and "2018"
.

Why is this and how do I fix it?

***Output***

```
How many times? 2

Enter time in military time notation: 
Hour  16
Minute  29

Enter time in military time notation: 
Hour  20
Minute  18
```

What should be exported:

```
1629
2018
```

Comment: Can you post more of the code?  Such as the declarations of hrTotal and minTotal

Comment: Sure. I just posted it.

Comment: Do you want to print the total or the individual hours/minutes?

Comment: I want to export all the hours and minutes inputted by the user. so if numOfTimes = 1 -- and they input 16 as the hour and 29 as the minute; I want the text file to contain "1629".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major modifications to make this code work.  First the `PrintWriter` must be declared and instantiated outside of the loop.  And the calls to `println` must occur inside of the loop.  Second, the `double`s must be converted to a `String` prior to printing and substring appropriately.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many times? ");
    int numOfTimes = in.nextInt();

    double hrTotal = 0;
    double minTotal = 0;

    PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter("Times.txt");

    for (int i = 1; i <= numOfTimes; i++) {

        System.out.println("\nEnter time in military time notation: ");
        System.out.print("Hour  ");
        double hrs1 = in.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Minute  ");
        double min1 = in.nextDouble();

        hrTotal += hrs1;
        minTotal += min1;
        String hrs = String.valueOf(hrs1);
        String min = String.valueOf(min1);
        p.println(hrs.substring(0, hrs.indexOf(".")) + min.substring(0,min.indexOf(".")));
    }
    p.close();
```

Before this change your code was adding the two doubles `hrs1` and `mins1` using actual arithmetic and it was using the static variables you had declared at the top of the class.

```
static double hrs1;
static double min1;
```

You should remove these static doubles since they are really never used.  Because the call to `println` was outside of the loop, it was causing the static doubles to be referenced instead of `hrs1` and `mins1` declared and assigned inside the loop.  You thought you were using the locals variables declared in the loop but they were never in scope.

Comment: @user3250237 Glad I could help.  I also included an explanation of what went wrong with your initial attempt.